# How to use change-detection on multiple folders in plan-repositories.yml

Tags: bamboo-specs

How to `change-detect` multiple folders inside Bamboo specs? I want to watch/detect all files inside folder1 and folder2. Also is this possible combined with `scope: global`?

Do I need to use the `file-filter-pattern` like this?

```yaml
- repository-name:
    scope: global
    change-detection:
        file-filter-type: include_only
        file-filter-pattern:
            - folder_parent/folder1/**
            - folder_parent/folder2/**
```

`repository-name` is a Linked Repository... Where I need two scenarios:

- PLAN1 needs to get triggered on folder1 and folder2.
- PLAN2 needs to get triggered on folder3